# How do I move an Entity back to its initial position

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

After applying a linear impulse and torque to a ball, I'm attempting to move the ball back to its initial position.

On load of the scene from Reality Composer, I'm storing the initial transform of the ball here

```
Experience.loadTestSphereAsync { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let anchor):
                anchor.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
                self.testSphereAnchor = anchor
                self.ball?.physicsBody?.mode = .static
                self.arView.scene.anchors.append(self.testSphereAnchor)
                self.ballStartTransform = self.testSphereAnchor.ball?.transform
                self.targetStartTransform = self.testSphereAnchor.target?.transform
                self.addTapGestures()
            case .failure(let error):
                fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

To move the ball back to its original position, I'm doing this

```
func didPressRestartButton() {
        ball?.clearForcesAndTorques()
        ball?.physicsBody?.mode = .static
        ball?.move(to: ballStartTransform!, relativeTo: nil, duration: 0.3)
    }
```

Instead of returning to the original position, the ball just freezes where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Set the physicsBody mode instead to .kinematic

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/physicsbodymode/kinematic